# Giraph job never ends

Tags: java, hadoop, graph, giraph

I'm trying to run the SimpleShortestPathsComputation example using the latest Giraph code and Hadoop 2.5.2. My command line looks like this:

```
hadoop jar /home/prhodes/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-2.5.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /user/prhodes/input/tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /user/prhodes/giraph_output/shortestpaths -w 4
```

And the job appears to start OK. But then it starts outputting these kinds of messages, and this just continues (seemingly) forever until you ctrl+c it.

```
15/03/11 02:54:31 INFO yarn.GiraphYarnClient: Giraph:
org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation, Elapsed:
305.43 secs 15/03/11 02:54:31 INFO yarn.GiraphYarnClient: appattempt_1426041786848_0002_000001, State: ACCEPTED, Containers
used: 1 15/03/11 02:54:35 INFO yarn.GiraphYarnClient: Giraph:
org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation, Elapsed:
309.44 secs 15/03/11 02:54:35 INFO yarn.GiraphYarnClient: appattempt_1426041786848_0002_000001, State: ACCEPTED, Containers
used: 1 15/03/11 02:54:39 INFO yarn.GiraphYarnClient: Giraph:
org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation, Elapsed:
313.45 secs 15/03/11 02:54:39 INFO yarn.GiraphYarnClient: appattempt_1426041786848_0002_000001, State: ACCEPTED, Containers
used: 1 15/03/11 02:54:43 INFO yarn.GiraphYarnClient: Giraph:
org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation, Elapsed:
317.45 secs 15/03/11 02:54:43 INFO yarn.GiraphYarnClient: appattempt_1426041786848_0002_000001, State: ACCEPTED, Containers
used: 1 ^C15/03/11 02:54:47 INFO yarn.GiraphYarnClient: Giraph:
org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation, Elapsed:
321.46 secs 15/03/11 02:54:47 INFO yarn.GiraphYarnClient: appattempt_1426041786848_0002_000001, State: ACCEPTED, Containers
used: 1
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an environmental issue.  I was trying to cherry pick with ports to whitelist in my AWS security group, and missed that YARN uses some ports for internal communication on the cluster.  Instead of trying to sort through the entire list, I just added a security group rule for "all traffic" to be accepted from 10.0.0.0/24.  That solved this problem.